# Фон страницы в виде диагональных линий

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, веб-дизайн

Для страницы сайта есть фоновая картинка в виде диагональных линий. Задавал ей `background-repeat`, но тогда стыковка заметна. При таком фоне наверное невозможно сделать маленький узор, а потом повторять его? Может на `CSS` лучше будет сделать, если такое возможно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отключить фоновое изображение и сделать `repeating-linear-gradient`

```css
  body {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,#222,red 10px, gold 10px) fixed;
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно сделать с помощью `linear-gradient()`

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 47%,rgba(111, 255, 255, 1) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%);
  background-size: 0.9rem 0.9rem;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Очень агрессивный фон в вопросе. Но как говорится, на каждый вкус,- свои фломастеры. 
Есть очень полезный онлайн ресурс для формирования фона -  https://www.transparenttextures.com/ 
Можно подобрать себе практически любой фон, с любым цветом. 
И в дальнейшем с помощью правил CSS скорректировать предпочитаемые цветовые оттенки.
Ваш вариант цвета - `background-color: #c52230;`
В принципе интерфейс интуитивно понятен, но на всякий случай кратко последовательность действий:

- Выбираете подходящий рисунок фона и нажимаете - `createWallpaper`
- Далее выбираете цвет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Выбираете нужный вам размер фона, брать лучше большой, чтобы не было
  сшивок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- И забираете код CSS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
   div {
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
background-color: #c52230;
background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/black-mamba.png");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Несколько фонов для примера

Пиксельный фон

```html
<style>
div {
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/3px-tile.png");
}
</style> 

<div></div>
```

Диагональный серый (хотите красный,- замените на `background-color: #c52230;`

```html
<style>
div {
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
background-color: #d5d5d5;
background-image: url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/black-twill.png);
}
</style> 

<div></div>
```

Фон Фибра

```html
<style>
div {
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
background-color: #ededed;
background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/carbon-fibre-big.png");
}
</style> 

<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно через svg

```
<div>
</div>

<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    background: url('line.svg') repeat center; // сама картинка https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DofB76Dmrwjy58coBb2g9SN_w5IlFwjB/view
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
</style>
```